# Datalog code not working in Racket

Tags: prolog, racket, datalog

I am trying to port [this Prolog code](http://www.anselm.edu/homepage/mmalita/culpro/graf1.html) to Datalog in Racket, using example at bottom of [this page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/datalog/datalog.html?q=datalog).

```
#lang datalog

edge(a, b). edge(b, c). edge(c, d). edge(d, a).
path(X, Y) :- edge(X, Y).
path(X, Y) :- edge(X, Z), path(Z, Y).
path(X, Y)?

pathall(X,X,[]).
pathall(X,Y,[X,Z|L]):- arc(X,Z),pathall(Z,Y,L).
pathall(a, d)?
```

But it is giving this error at `[X,Z|L]` on last line of code:

```
read: expected a `]' to close `['
```

How do I represent a list in Datalog? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datalog is a syntactic **subset** of Prolog.

In particular, compound terms such as *lists* are *not* supported in Datalog.

Comment: So, it may be best to use Prolog iteself for such tasks. Any other Scheme that takes Prolog code? Or Haskell?

Comment: In the context of these questions, my personal recommendation is to use Prolog directly: It is a full-fledged programming language and also has a built-in database. Why not jump directly to the real thing?